Which permission level controls the ability to share?
I'm looking at the default SharePoint groups:
Owner
Member
Visitor

Which of the above have ability to share?

I can also create a new SharePoint group by choosing a set of permissions. Which permissions provide the sharing ability?



Default SharePoint Groups' Ability to Share
Owners: Yes
Members: No
Visitors: No

Option 1:
You can create a custom permission level:

Option 2:  Allow your members to share (I'd go for this one)


Option 3: If you don't care about any other aspects create a new SharePoint group with Full Control.

1.Share with internal users: Owner, Member and Visitor all can share.
2.Share with external users: Go to the site permissions settings -> Site Sharing -> Change how members can share.


My users in visitor group cannot share with others. Why would that be?
